# How to render & insert alphabets row within the MS sql server records?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Database Records:
[image]

I want to represent as record set using stored procedure.

I have many records likewise in MS SQL DataBase.

It will be Listing record groupby A, B, C .. Z wize..
Automatically insert the Alphabets while got output from SQL Table.

I want below output from procedure..

[image]

How it will possible using Stored Procedure..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT` and [`UNION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for this, though you will still get a 3 columns row for the rows that contains only the first letter:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T as TABLE 
(
    Name varchar(20),
    Location varchar(20),
    CreatedOn date
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('Alex macwan', 'New york', '2015-12-10'),
('Jone Dinee', 'Denmark', '2016-05-01'),
('Jolly llb', 'USA', '2016-01-02'),
('Amin Mark', 'India', '2015-01-08'),
('Ben Denis', 'Brazil', '2015-10-02')
```

The query:

```
SELECT Name, Location, CreatedOn
FROM @T
UNION 
SELECT LEFT(Name, 1), NULL, NULL
FROM @T
ORDER BY Name
```

Results:

```
Name                 Location             CreatedOn
-------------------- -------------------- ----------
A                    NULL                 NULL
Alex macwan          New york             2015-12-10
Amin Mark            India                2015-01-08
B                    NULL                 NULL
Ben Denis            Brazil               2015-10-02
J                    NULL                 NULL
Jolly llb            USA                  2016-01-02
Jone Dinee           Denmark              2016-05-01
```